# Corrupted ZIP file download

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I'm trying to create ZIP file using SharpZipLib and send it to the client, in pages where there is no grid the code works fine and all ok but in a page that have a grid the file is always corrupted.

I tried to use HttpContext.Current.Response.End() in the end of the ZIP file download method and it worked but this means ThreadAbortException and I can't do extra code afterwards

Here is the code I used to create and download the ZIP file

```
Public Function ExportToZIPFile(ByVal dataTable As DataTable, orderID As Integer, downloadedZIPFileName As String, ByRef zipFilePassword As String) As Boolean
    Dim isSuccess As Boolean = False
    Dim excelFilePath As String = Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Test.xls")
    Try
        Using streamWriter As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(excelFilePath)
            For i As Integer = 0 To dataTable.Columns.Count - 1
                streamWriter.Write(dataTable.Columns(i).ToString().ToUpper() & vbTab)
            Next

            streamWriter.WriteLine()
            For i As Integer = 0 To (dataTable.Rows.Count) - 1

                For j As Integer = 0 To dataTable.Columns.Count - 1

                    If dataTable.Rows(i)(j) IsNot Nothing Then
                        streamWriter.Write(Convert.ToString(dataTable.Rows(i)(j)) & vbTab)
                    Else
                        streamWriter.Write(vbTab)
                    End If
                Next

                streamWriter.WriteLine()
            Next

            streamWriter.Close()
        End Using

        zipFilePassword = "123456"

        SendPasswordInMessage(orderID, zipFilePassword)

        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/x-zip-compressed"
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + downloadedZIPFileName + ".zip")

        Using zipOutput As ZipOutputStream = New ZipOutputStream(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream)
            zipOutput.Password = zipFilePassword
            Dim ZipEntry As ZipEntry = New ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(excelFilePath))
            zipOutput.PutNextEntry(ZipEntry)
            Using fread = File.OpenRead(excelFilePath)
                Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(8191) {}
                ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Core.StreamUtils.Copy(fread, zipOutput, buffer)
            End Using

            zipOutput.Finish()
        End Using

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
        isSuccess = True
    Catch tah As ThreadAbortException

    Catch ex As Exception
        MStartLogger.Error(ex, Me.GetType.Name, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, "")
    Finally
        If File.Exists(excelFilePath) Then
            File.Delete(excelFilePath)
        End If
    End Try
    Return isSuccess
End Function
```

I think the issue is that the HttpContext.Current.Response doesn't take it's time to create the file and download it so I'm expecting to create the ZIP file download it and return with a success message to my previous code

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in limiting buffer array by 8191 in this line

`Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(8191) {}`

I suggest changing it to something like

`Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(fread.length) {}`

Comment: It is only a buffer for the Copy method to use as needed. The size does not matter (for the purposes of the question). It will in effect fill it up and empty the buffer as many times as needed.